# How can I reference a picture that consists of two images, (a) and (b), but the file already has both images?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats, subfig

I need a picture in my document, which in one file already has the two images. I just need to reference the figure as Figure 1a and Figure 1b in the text. I tried to do this with the `subfig` package, but the image shows the a and b labels, which are also already printed in the image file.

The result of the reference in the text is fine, I would like to remove the a and b labels produced by the `\subfloat` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[\label{sub:1}]{}
\subfloat[\label{sub:2}]{}
\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub:1,sub:2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution that uses the machinery of the `subcaption` package. It employs the fact that what's really needed is a way to suitably increment the `subfigure` counter twice. One way of doing so is to issue `\caption` statements twice. Another way -- the one pursued here -- is to execute the low-level `\refstepcounter{subfigure}` instruction twice. As `\refstepcounter` produces no visible output, it's not necessary to do anything special to "hide" the empty subcaptions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
       \begin{subfigure}{1sp}
       \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{sub:1}
       \refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{sub:2}
       \end{subfigure}
\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub:1,sub:2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and temporarily set the `labelformat` to be `empty` for two `\subcaptionbox`es, then include the image as-is via `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{sub:1}}{}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{sub:2}}{}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{General caption}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub:1,sub:2}

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to include clipped versions of the original image (using [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox), for example), and then use your standard sub-figure package for presenting them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image}}% Capture image in box 1
  % Trimming is: trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>
  % Set an appropriate value for <bottom> to trim/clip out the embedded subfigure labels (a), (b)
  \subcaptionbox{\label{sub:1}}[0.5\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[trim=0pt 35pt \fpeval{0.5*\wd1}pt 0pt,clip,width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \subcaptionbox{\label{sub:2}}[0.5\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[trim=\fpeval{0.5*\wd1}pt 35pt 0pt 0pt,clip,width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \caption{General caption}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\cref{sub:1,sub:2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the optional command of `\subfloat`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat{\label{sub:1}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\qquad
        \subfloat{\label{sub:2}\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
        \caption{General caption}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
    
    \cref{sub:1,sub:2}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the directives `\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}`, `\qquad`, and `\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}` needed, or even helpful? The OP has stated that there's a single graphics file to be displayed.